# How to prepare nullable integers for Validation

Tags: php, laravel

The number of referees and the away team score are both nullable if the game is in the future.

Is it possible to use Laravel's `prepareForValidation` to sanitize the data in a way that does not convert null to zero?

I tried these, but they didn't work:

```php
protected function prepareForValidation() {
  'referees' => (int) $this->referees,
  'away_team_score' => filter_var($this->away_team_score, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),
}
```

`(int)` will convert empty fields to 0.

filter_var($var, , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) is an error because the function returns and empty string/false. It will force an error: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'away_team_score' at row 1 (SQL: update `games` set `game_time` = 11:50, `away_team_score` = , `games`.`updated_at` =

The user submitted data is also validated.

```php
'referees' => 'integer|min:0|max:10|nullable'
```

I'd like to have the best of both worlds: data preparation for nullable integers and then run validations while accepting null values.

Comment: `if ($this->referees === "") $this->merge(["referees" => null]);`

Comment: @miken32: adding your code after it goes through filter_var works. Thank you.  I'm hoping for a one line, easily to repeat code because there are hundreds of variables to do this to and lean is more maintainable.

Comment: I'd suggest sticking with an integer value such as 0 or -1 instead of null if you also want to validate it as an integer. This way `(int)$this->referees` will still get you what you want while still protecting against bad user input.

Comment: @miken32: Using other values don't work.  Those values would have to be removed when creating reports, a process I'm not in control of.  sidenote: I've like using -1 for a missing code; I've used it a lot.